# Need to customize catalog listing and filter in backstage

Tags: backstage

I want some help on [backstage.io](https://backstage.io). When I open UI of backstage on my local it shows me the catalog page. On the catalog page, I see the listing of my components and left-hand side of the same I see a panel for data filtering with few dropdowns. I need to customize that panel. How can I do that?